# Fedora 20 won't boot after changing ownership of everything in /var to Apache

Tags: linux, fedora

It flashes to a blank screen a few times, perhaps trying to load cinammon desktop, then hangs here [image: []]

I accidentally chowned the ownership of everything in /var to the apache group, which caused a few problems (like, it killed mysql) which I fixed. Then on reboot, I get this. How can I recover this?

---

UPDATE

This is what I have done so far:

1. Booted as a single user which mounted the hdd with command prompt
2. Run the following which reset all permissions and groups

   for p in $(rpm -qa); do rpm --setperms $p; done

   for p in $(rpm -qa); do rpm --setugids $p; done

This has sorted the problem I had with /var, but I still can't boot. I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: it's hanging on "wait for plymouth boot screen to quit". I think this is because /var/logs no longer has the correct permissions - my question really is now, how can I change permissions on that directory? I'm using virtualbox.

Comment: Tried everything, even installed fedora 21, ended up doing a fresh install